# SSL configuration in tomcat and apr

Tags: java, tomcat7

I'm facing a problem setting up my tomcat with apr native lib, 
I have the following:

```
Tomcat: 7.0.42
Java: 1.7.0_40-b43
OS: Centos 6.4 (2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.i686)
APR: 1.3.9
Native lib: 1.1.27
OpenSSL: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.i686
```

My server.xml looks like:

```
...
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
...
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
SSLCertificateFile="/tmp/monitoringPortalCert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="/tmp/monitoringPortalKey.pem"
SSLPassword="hide"
/>
...
```

I compiled the native lib as follow:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-ssl=yes --prefix=$CATALINA_HOME 
make && make install
```

The APR is loaded ok:

```
Oct 06, 2013 7:55:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.3.9.
```

But I'm still having this error:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize the SSLEngine.
org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 70023: This function has not been implemented on this  platform
```

Could you guys help to understand where my error is? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your support.

---

Thanks for the comment Mark, below it is the ./configure / make && make install outcome:
./configure

```
[root@localhost native]# ./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-ssl=yes --    prefix=$CATALINA_HOME && make && make install
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
Tomcat Native Version: 1.1.27
checking for chosen layout... tcnative
checking for APR... yes
  setting CC to "gcc"
  setting CPP to "gcc -E"
checking for JDK location (please wait)... /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40 from environment
checking Java platform... checking Java platform...
checking for sablevm... NONE
  adding "-I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/include" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
checking os_type directory...  linux
  adding "-I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/include/linux" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for OpenSSL library... using openssl from /usr/lib and /usr/include
checking OpenSSL library version... ok
checking for OpenSSL DSA support... yes
  setting TCNATIVE_LDFLAGS to "-lssl -lcrypto"
  adding "-DHAVE_OPENSSL" to CFLAGS
  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to ""
  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to " /usr/lib/libapr-1.la  -lpthread"
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating tcnative.pc
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing default commands
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-    src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-    src/jni/native'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-  src/jni/native'
/usr/lib/apr-1/build/mkdir.sh /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/include/apr-1 /usr/apache-   tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig \
                 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tcnative.pc /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig/tcnative-  1.pc
list=''; for i in $list; do \
            ( cd $i ; make DESTDIR= install ); \
    done
/bin/sh /usr/lib/apr-1/build/libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c -m 755     libtcnative-1.la /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27 /usr/apache-    tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-  1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0 || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so.0 && ln -s libtcnative-   1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-   1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so && ln -s libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27   libtcnative-1.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.lai /usr/apache-tomcat-  7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.a /usr/apache-tomcat-   7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/local/apr/lib'
```

make && make install:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-  src/jni/native'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
/usr/lib/apr-1/build/mkdir.sh /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/include/apr-1 /usr/apache-   tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig \
                 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tcnative.pc /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig/tcnative- 1.pc
list=''; for i in $list; do \
            ( cd $i ; make DESTDIR= install ); \
    done
/bin/sh /usr/lib/apr-1/build/libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c -m 755     libtcnative-1.la /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27 /usr/apache-  tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-   1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0 || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so.0 && ln -s libtcnative-  1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-  1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so && ln -s libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27    libtcnative-1.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.lai /usr/apache-tomcat-  7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.a /usr/apache-tomcat-  7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/local/apr/lib'
```

It seems everything is fine, but the error is not self-explanatory

Answer (score 13):

I also faced exact issue. Problem was it was not detecting correctly installed native library.

When You install native library, before that install these first.

For Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev libssl-dev

These libraries are required instead of libtcnative. After they have been successfully installed, configure your app n this manner.

```
sudo ./configure --with-apr=`which apr-1-config` --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME --with-ssl=yes --prefix=$CATALINA_HOME
```

Here CATALINA_HOME is your tomcat home that you have set or directly use /opt/apache_tomcat_version

Then

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

After installation is finished , it will update you that libraries have not been put in tomcat's lib folder.

Configure your setenv like this

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Restart your tomcat, you're all Done!

Cheers

Comment: Please mention exact issue log during configuration or there was no error at all ?

Comment: In case if you still find same error, run `sudo make clean` before running `sudo ./configure --with...` and it should work!

Comment: Thank you so much, after 4 days of effort, finally only your solution worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

Go back and check the results of ./configure as it look like the OpenSSL libraries have not been found.

Answer (score 0):

On `Ubuntu 12.04`, like Mark Thomas has pinpointed above I had not installed the prerequisite libs before I built the `tcnative` (tomcat native) library. As mentioned in the [official webpage](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) all I had to do was :

```
apt-get install libapr1.0-dev libssl-dev
```

and after that rebuild the tomcat native library, i.e., redo the `configure`, `make && make install`

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, working on a RHEL 6.6 system, I had to fork/copy an already existing Tomcat branch (such as /opt/tomcat/DEFAULT_BRANCH/conf /opt/tomcat/DEFAULT_BRANCH/ etc) and it was known-to-be-working already with previous forks.

Therefore recompiling wasn't an option and even when I tried recompiling per the suggestions in this post, I always ran into the same SSL Engine problem in Catalina.out

What I ended up going was commenting the "Listener className" entry from the server.xml file (Line 27) and I then followed the following steps and it ended up working:

https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is that the version of `openssl` used by `libcnative` is different from the version of `openssl` currently used by `tomcat`. So, you can just recompile `libcnative` with the option:

```
--with-ssl=`the openssl directory used by tomcat`
```

It may be suitable for an OS in which there are many `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` of different version.